# resize2fs: Invalid argument while trying to resize /dev/sda1 (dd problems)

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, dd

I was attempting to copy my Ubuntu installation to a larger HDD following [this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=599599) with the `dd` command. The guide says:

> "It's recommended you dd to an identical partition for optimal results."

but I have a feeling that it is actually mandatory and that this is the root of the issue. Since it didn't make it seem too important that the partitions were the same size I made a partition or roughly the same size, leaning to a little larger, on the new drive using gparted. The guide also didn't say that you couldn't be running off of the drive you were cloning so I was booted from it. After running `dd  if=/dev/sdc6 of=/dev/sda1` from the guide, which neglected to mention the the uuid would be copied creating new issues that had to be corrected, I rebooted and tried to mount the new cloned partion but am given:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

So I looked up how to fix a bad super block, I figure it is the super block because `tune2fs` complained about it when fixing the uuid, and found a [filesystem failure guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/surviving-a-linux-filesystem-failures.html) that said `e2fsck -f /dev/sda1` should fix the issue. It instead gives me the error:

```
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 18037760 blocks
The physical size of the device is 17948416 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort<y>?
```

So I look up how to correct mismatching partition sizes and find a forum question on that topic with everyone saying `resize2fs -f /dev/sda1` should resolve it but that gives me the error output:

```
resize2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/sda1 to 17948416 (4k) blocks.
resize2fs: Invalid argument while trying to resize /dev/sda1
Please run 'e2fsck -fy /dev/sda1' to fix the filesystem
after the aborted resize operation.
```

When I look up the `resize2fs` error I can only find bug reports and other low-level things that don't help me. Which just loops me back to the previous problem. So my question is: Can I fix the partition size, or is there some other step I need to take?

I would prefer not to have to reclone the drive as it took over 16 hours to do it(that may be because I was booted off it, the drive is only 72Gb).

Comment: Oh well, I really wanted to be done so I reformatted the drive and used the `cp` option from the `dd` guide.

Comment: The UUID conflict is only relevant if you mount both the old and the new partition. Don't mount them both, and you're fine.

Comment: I have this problem too.